# Getting error 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load /socket.io' in case of socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, nginx, websocket

I am getting error:"XMLHttpRequest cannot load /socket.io " for socket call. what's wrong there,i am not getting it.i am new to web sockets,my other api call is running good,but socket.io call is not working. i have installed ssl certificate for nginx,help me guys.

My nginx configuration is

```
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
 #listen 80;
listen 443  ssl;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name www.example.com;
        ssl_certificate "/home/oodles4/sslcertificate/public.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key "/home/oodles4/sslcertificate/keyfile.key";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains";

 #location / {
                 root  "/home/oodles4/Documents/dcx/user/dev";
                #root  "/home/oodles4/Documents/dcx/explorer";
                index home.html home.htm;
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
  #      }
        location /{
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO           $fastcgi_script_name;
                                                                                                                              9,51           2%
 #location / {
                 root  "/home/oodles4/Documents/dcx/user/dev";
                #root  "/home/oodles4/Documents/dcx/explorer";
                index home.html home.htm;
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
  #      }
        location /{
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO           $fastcgi_script_name;

            fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL        $server_protocol;
            fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
            fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
            fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
            fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;
            fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR         $server_addr;
            fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT         $server_port;
            fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME         $server_name;
            fastcgi_param   HTTPS               on;
            fastcgi_param   HTTP_SCHEME         https;
}
        location /admin{
                alias "/home/oodles4/Documents/dcx/admin/dev";
                index home.html home.htm;
        }

        location /api {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/api;
        }

        location /admin/api{
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/api;
        }


 location /explorer{
                alias "/home/oodles4/Documents/dcx/explorer";
#                try_files $uri $uri/ /views/main/main.html;
                index dev/views/main/main.html;
      }

        location /explorer/api{
                proxy_pass    http://localhost:3000/api;
        }
```

when i do '/explorer', my all api's call and socket will work

```
var socket = io.connect('http://www.example.com:3000', {
      'reconnect': true,
      'reconnection delay': 500
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have server blocks to listen on ports 80, 443.
but you do not have any server block to listen on 3000.
Here i assume that you have any application running on port 3000.

Just append this block to current nginx configuration.

```
server {
     server_name example.com www.example.com;
     location / {
         proxy_pass    http://localhost:3000/;
     }
}
```